# PHP: Updating data with foreign key

Tags: php, sql

I'm currently doing an update for a list of items and it contains a few foreign keys. I have 4 tables which are:

Item (**itemId**,itemName)

Staff (**staffid**,staffName,staffPassword,staffEmail,staffTypeId*)

Item_Staff(**itemstaffid**,itemid*,staffid*,itemqtty,expireddate,instockdate,itemstatus)

Stafftype(**stafftypeid**,stypeName)

My problem is I can edit the item details in the form but the item details is not updated even though it is still redirected to the display page. It does not have any error so I was wondering where is the logic error was.
So far these are the codes that I've tried.

pedit-item.php

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$itemstaffid=$_GET['itemstaffid'];    
$qry=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * from item_staff d INNER JOIN item i ON d.itemID=i.itemID INNER JOIN staff s ON d.staffID=s.staffID");
while ($res=mysqli_fetch_array($qry))
  {
    $itemstaffid = $_POST['itemStaffId'];
    $itemid=$res['itemid'];
    $staffid=$res['staffid'];
    $itemqtty=$res['itemqtty'];
    $expireddate=$res['expireddate'];
    $instockdate=$res['instockdate'];
    $itemstatus=$res['itemstatus'];
  }

if (isset($_POST['update']))
  {
    $itemstaffid=$_POST['itemstaffid'];
    $itemid = $_POST['itemid'];
    $staffid = $_POST['staffid'];
    $itemqtty=$_POST['itemqtty'];
    $expireddate=$_POST['expireddate'];
    $instockdate=$_POST['instockdate'];
    $itemstatus=$_POST['itemstatus'];

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE item_staff set itemstaffid='$itemstaffid',itemid='$itemid',staffid='$staffid',itemqtty='$itemqtty',expireddate='$expireddate',instockdate='$instockdate',itemstatus='$itemstatus' where 'itemstaffid'='$itemstaffid'" );
    
    if ($result)
    {
      header("location: update-item.php");
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Failed";
    }
  }
```

Then, I want to display it here.

```
 $sql="SELECT * from item_staff d INNER JOIN item i ON d.itemID=i.itemID INNER JOIN staff s ON d.staffID=s.staffID";
  $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $row=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if ($row > 0)
   {
     while ($res=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>'.$res['itemStaffId'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$res['itemId'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$res['staffId'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$res['itemQtty'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$res['expiredDate'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$res['inStockDate'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$res['itemstatus'].'</td>';
      echo "<td><a href= \"edit-item.php?itemStaffId=$res[itemStaffId]\"><input type='submit' value='EDIT'></a>";
      echo "<td><a href= \"delete.php?itemStaffId=$res[itemStaffId]\"><input type='submit' value='DELETE'></a>";
      echo '</tr>';
                        }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your variable `$itemstaffid` has been overwritten in the `if` block, so when executing the query the `where` clause will not find the desired record. You should show your update query for testing.